# A faster way of creating unique item list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I implemented a code which creates vocabulary list like below. `q` and `a` is `list of string` and `s` is `list of list of string`. Although it is working, it is really slow because `data` is quite big. And I think this code is not so smart.

Do you think is there any way to implement gracefully?

```
 vocab = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (set(list(chain.from_iterable(s)) + q + a) for s, q, a in data))
```

I wrote a simple program to test this code. As like below, `data` length is quite large in actual dataset.

```
 import time                                                                                                                                                 
 import functools                                                                                                                                            
 from itertools import chain                                                                                                                                 

 s1 = [                                                                                                                                                      
 ['a', 'b', 'fwa'], # actual length is around 10                                                                                                                                 
 ['foo', 'ixb', 'fwa'],                                                                                                                                      
 ['fj', 'fab', 'fwa']                                                                                                                                        
 ]                                                                                                                                                           

 q1 = ['fwa', 'fawh'] # actual length is around 10                                                                                                                                

 a1 = ['fjj', 'jfaw'] # actual length is around 3                                                                                                                                 

 data = []                                                                                                                                                   
 for i in range(10000000):                                                                                                                                    
     data.append((s1, q1, a1))                                                                                                                               


 start = time.time()                                                                                                                                         
 vocab = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (set(list(chain.from_iterable(s)) + q + a) for s, q, a in data)) # my way                                      
 elapsed_time = time.time() - start                                                                                                                          
 print(elapsed_time) # 11.522738695144653                                                                                                                                         
 print(vocab)                                                                                                                                                

 start = time.time()                                                                                                                                         
 vocab = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (set(chain(chain.from_iterable(s), q, a)) for s, q, a in data)) # @cowbert                                     
 elapsed_time = time.time() - start                                                                                                                          
 print(elapsed_time) # 9.918306350708008                                                                                                                                  
 print(vocab)
```

Comment: can you provide sample input and output? it's hard to follow...

Comment: I wrote a simple code.

Comment: sorry, misread the problem (deleted comment). Could you try nested `chain` instead of using `+` if that is causing the problem? Like `set(list(chain(chain.from_iterable(s), q, a)))`?

Comment: @cowbert show my updated code. its a little faster. I think to avoid `reduce` and `|` may be better performance..

Comment: with that many elements, `reduce()` probably going to be the main contributor to the speed; is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: will usiing `vocab = collections.deque()`  and `vocab.appendleft()` in a normal `for` loop be faster than `reduce()` in this case? (we still have to invoke a function but we're calling a C function and not a lamba)